# Differences in Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

If you have class B which inherits from class A, the two values printed below might be different. Why?

```
B *myPointer = new B();
A *myOtherPointer = myPointer;

printf(“%x”, myPointer);
printf(“%x”, myOtherPointer);
```

Comment: Woah, don't. Don't ask all this in one question. Make it... one question per question. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and *try* answering yourself first. People will help, but no one will do your homework for you.

Comment: What the heck is a "output operator"? Do you refer to "<<"? Ha ha

Comment: Wait a bloody second, are we taking this quiz for him?

Comment: Please use a more specific title for your question(s).

Comment: I've rolled this back to one question per question...

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to have been asked in good faith.  It's a request for free tutoring.  Also, take a look at the detail of the close reason.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's a very vague reason for closing.  I don't think you can define "good faith" questions.

Comment: So reopen it...  It's already attracted two mod flags and several edits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I am not sure about previous versions, but as it stands it seems like a proper question.

Comment: If this is a quiz question, I'm awfully leery of answering it outright...

Comment: Sorry but i have provided some of my solutions, which were deleted. I have tried to answer this question but it is kind of a corner and trivial case, and that is why I am seeking help from gurus like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the two values printed below might be different. Why?

Assuming that `A` is a base of `B` so that the assignment is valid, it might not be the only base of `B` (and in particular it might not be the *first* base), in which case there will be an offset:

```
struct A { int x; };
struct A_ { int y; }
struct B : A_, A {};
int main() {
   B b;
   assert( static_cast<void*>(&b) != static_cast<void*>(static_cast<A*>(&b)) );
}
```

Additionally, if the inheritance relationship is virtual then they will not start at the same address either:

```
struct A {};
struct B : virtual A {};
int main() {
   B b;
   assert( static_cast<void*>(&b) != static_cast<void*>(static_cast<A*>(&b)) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer seems very advanced. I have not seen struct or virtual inheritance. Could you please briefly explain those concepts? I know struct is similar to class in C++.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are *almost* synonyms, with the difference that the default access specifier for `struct` is public and for `class` is private. `struct B : A_, A {};` is equivalent to the more verbose: `class B : public A_, public A { public: };`. Virtual inheritance is a whole different beast for which an explanation in a comment would not really suffice. The most concise (imprecise) description would be *inheritance where the derived type is willing to share the base subobject under some circumstances* (you should really google/read more than this :)

Comment: @MK: A pointer is always a pointer, but the value of two different pointers can differ (obviously). I am not sure if you did not understand the answer or I did not understand your comment...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas but you are setting one pointer to be equal to the other pointer.  In C this is a simple operation which doesn't care about what the pointers point to.  And in C++, apparently, there is some scary magic that happens during pointer assignment.

Comment: @MK: In C++ there are different types of casts for pointers, `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` handle this particular cases, where because of multiple/virtual inheritance the subobjects are not located in the same address. In C, a pointer cast is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast` (plus optionally `const_cast`) in C++ (which again, differs to the behavior of the C cast syntax in C++